# undefined method "should_not_be_blank"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I am on the steep Rails learning curve and am working 'the' Rails Tutorial

All of my tests pass except this one. I get an NoMethodError: undefined method 'should_not_be_blank' for "foorbars": string

here is the test:

it "should set the encrypted password" do

```
                @user.encrypted_password.should_not_be_blank
```

end

I can only assume that this method is no longer part of Rails 3.1.0.?
If not what should i write instead? Where should I be looking for a the list of supported methods?

your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@user.encrypted_password.should_not be_blank
```

It should work fine.